# Are $\delta(x-5)$ and $\delta(5-x)$ the same function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, dirac-delta

As the title says, I'm confused whether $\delta(x-5)$ and $\delta(5-x)$ are the same function.

Similarly, are $\delta(x-5,y-6)$ and $\delta(5-x,6-y)$ the same function?

To, me it seems they are! But want a second opinion!

Comment: Be careful with what words you use. $\delta$ is usually not considered a function, as $\delta(0)$ doesn't really have a value. It's often _called_ a function, because notationally it looks like one, and for most inputs it behaves like one. But technically that's incorrect.

Comment: Yeah. That was my guess as well!

Comment: what is your definition of $\delta(x-c)$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: You should use the definition $\delta(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{2} 1_{|x| < 1/n}$, limit in the sense of distributions that is integrating on continuous functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\delta_t$ produces a distribution, meaning it generates a linear map $T_{\delta_t} : C_c^\infty \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $\textit{defined}$ by

$$T_{\delta_t} (\phi) = <\delta, \phi > = \int \delta(t) \phi(t)dt :=\phi(0) $$
The first three equalities are all simply the same thing with different notation.The integral is more formal and makes computations more clear. In fact $\delta$ is homogeneous of degree -1 meaning that
$$\delta(\alpha x) = \frac{\delta(x)}{|\alpha|}$$
for $\alpha  \neq 0$. This can be shown by scaling the integral. So $\alpha = -1$ gives $\delta(x) = \delta(-x)$ as a distribution. Thus
$$T_{\delta_{x-5}}(\phi) = \int\delta(x-5)\phi(x)dx = \phi(5) = \int\delta(5-x)\phi(x) = T_{\delta_{5-x}}(\phi)$$
And similarly for the 2 dimensional case.

Answer (score -2):

The expression $\delta(t)$ accepts as input a real number $t$, and returns as output either the number $1$, if $t=0$, or else the number zero, if $t\neq 0$. That is
$$
\delta(t)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 & \quad \text{if}\, t = 0 \\
0 & \quad \text{if}\, t\neq 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
If follows from this definition that $\delta(5-x)$ is equal to $1$ if and only if $5-x=0$, that is, if and only if $5=x$, and $\delta(x-5)$ is equal to $1$ if and only if $x-5=0$, that is, again, if and only $5=x$. Conclusion: $\delta(5-x)=\delta(x-5)$ for every real $x$, and more generally $\delta(a-b)=\delta(b-a)$ for every pair of real numbers $a,b$.

Comment: This is a fine answer, assuming one specific notion of the $\delta$. The other definition, where "$\delta(0) = \infty$" (which, the way I encounter it, is formally defined by how it behaves as a factor of an integrand) requires more care. It is not clear which one the OP is referring to.

Comment: @Arthur - Can you please point out a mathematical reference where "$\delta(0)=\infty$" is a formal definition?

Comment: Did I say that that "$\delta(0) = \infty$" was a formal definition? I didn't mean to. That's why I used the quotation marks, and noted that the formal definition was in terms of integrals. Have a loook at, for instance, [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) to see what I'm referring to.

Comment: With all due respect, Wikipedia is not the best reference for mathematics. But anyway, the way I understand the OP's question, is this "Is the expression $\delta(x-5)$ equal to the expression $\delta(5-x)$"? To answer it, I could have invoked the definition of the delta "function" in the distribution sense and arrive at the same result. Since my intuition was that the OP would not profit much from these elaborate, formal considerations, I preferred to simplify the argument as much as possible. Obviously someone does not agree with me.

Comment: In signal processing, this is indeed the definition that is used. Since the question is tagged as Signal Processing, I don't see anything wrong with this answer.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion in this answer between the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ inthe OP's question, and the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$.